# Ошибка Codeigniter "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Получаю ошибку "Trying to get property of non-object".**

Мой файл контролера:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Fees extends Admin_Controller {

/**
 * Constructor
 */
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

             // load model class
            $this->load->model("fees_model");
            $this->load->library('fees');
}



 * Fees
 */
function index()
{
  // get fees
  $fees = $this->fees_model->get_fees();

    // setup page header data
      $this
        ->set_title(lang('admin title fee'));

    $data = $this->includes;

    // set content data
    $content_data = array(
                    'fees'   => $fees,
        'cancel_url' => "/admin",
    );

    // load views
    $data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/fees/index', $content_data, TRUE);
    $this->load->view($this->template, $data);
}
```

}

Мой файл библиотеки Fees.php

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Fees
{

    var $view=array();

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $site = $CI->db->select("card_check, card_fee")
        ->where("ID", 1)
        ->get("fees");

        if($site->num_rows() == 0) {
            $CI->template->error(
                "You are missing the site settings database row."
            );
        } else {
            $this->view = $site->row();
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Мой файл модели;

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Fees_model extends CI_Model {

/**
 * @vars
 */
private $_db;


/**
 * Constructor
 */
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    // define primary table
    $this->_db = 'fees';
}

function updateFees($data) 
  {
      $this->db->where("ID", 1)->update("fees", $data);
  }

function get_fees()
  {
    return $this->db->get("fees");
  }
```

}

**Что я сделал не так и почему получаю эту ошибку?**

Благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: Где ошибка то сама? Обычно должно писать файл, строку, хоть какой нибудь трейс.

Comment: Ругается на <?php echo $this->fees->view->card_fee ?>. Ошибка "A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$fees"